# My MySQL function totally loses math precision when multiplying decimals. Why is that?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I made this simple function, and the result returns 1 rather than 0.5

What did I do wrong?

```
DELIMITER //

DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS test_decimal //

CREATE FUNCTION test_decimal(input DECIMAL)
  RETURNS DECIMAL
BEGIN
  SET @_credit = 0.5;
  RETURN input * @_credit;
END //

DELIMITER ;

SELECT test_decimal(1);
```

Comment: What happens if `@_credit` is *typed* as DECIMAL as well? (That is, could it be typed as something else by chance?)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because you didn't specify the `precision` and `scale` that's why it's rounding the value.  The precision represents the number of significant digits that are stored for values, and the scale represents the number of digits that can be stored following the decimal point. By default, the value of the precision is `10` and the value of scale is `0`. So, `RETURNS DECIMAL` is the same as `RETURNS DECIMAL(10,0)`. If the scale is 0, *DECIMAL values contain no decimal point or fractional part*.  Try specifying in to your function.

```
RETURNS DECIMAL(5,2) -- 999.99
```

**[DECIMAL, NUMERIC](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fixed-point-types.html)**

## [SQLFiddle Sample](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bd177/1)